# Object [id=XYZ] is not a known entity type

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipselink, tomcat9

I created a new Dynamic Web Project with the JPA facet enabled. My project only contains the persistance.xml file, one annotated entity and the persistence code.

When I try to execute the persistence code I the the following error: Object: is not a known Entity type.

I am running an running Eclipse 4.12.0. Please assist.

PERSISTANCE UNIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ezimax" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>za.co.ezimax.entity.Profile</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ezimax_backend"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

ENTITY

```
package za.co.ezimax.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity()
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name="sex", nullable = false)
    private int sex;

    @Column(name="sex", nullable = false)
    private String mobileMac;

    @Column(name="sex", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String mobileNo;

    @Column(name="birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate registrationDate;

    @Column(name="user_password", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private char[] userPassword;

    public Profile() {
    }
}
```

PERSISTENCE CODE

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ezimax");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setFirstName("Hendre");
        profile.setLastName("Louw");
        profile.setSex(1);
        profile.setMobileMac("ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff");
        profile.setMobileNo("+27830000000");
        profile.setRegistrationDate(LocalDate.now());
        profile.setUserPassword("password".toCharArray());

        em.persist(profile);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
```

MAVEN

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Note that when asking about errors/exceptions you should provide the entire message along with the stacktrace. That being said I suspect that EclipseLink 2.7.1 doesn't know how to map `LocalDate` so you'd either have to upgrade to a version that supports this, provide some mapping for that (in Hibernate you could use a custom UserType) or use the old `java.util.Date`.

Comment: [Guide](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-persistence-xml/) on persistence.xml which provides an example for eclipselink

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 2.7.4 and the issue was resolved.